# get email of contact from account with the accountid

Tags: apex, soql, email

I have one contact in one of my account.
I have the account id of that account.
I am trying to get the email of the contact in my account with a soql query but it is returned blank :

```
contact em = [select name,email from contact where Accountid =:add];
```

To retrieve the email I then do em.mail. But that is empty.

add is my account id that I know

[image]

Comment: There are many problems with this. If more than record is retrieved it will fail. You are also saying em.mail when the results would be em.email. It is very possible that there could be multiple contacts with emails for one account

Comment: So what would be the best way to contact the specific email from the contact I have for that account ?

Comment: Is Person Account enabled in your org ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`email` may work in apex but in Lightning it will fail as its wrong API name. Correct API is `Email`.

Change query to below (does not hurt to leave as is but you will get confused when implementing in lightning)

```
contact em = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact where AccountId =:add];
```

Now wherever you are referring to email in lightning component, change it to `Email` (case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

You are not being specific enough so you have two options. If you are looking for a specific record then

```
 contact em = [select name, email from contact where accountdId=:add and name ='sdasadsda' limit 1];
em.email;
```

would have the information

```
list<contact> emlist = [select name ,email from contact where accountId=:add];
for(contact c : emlist) {
  system.debug('Name: ' + c.name + ' : Email: ' + c.email);
}
```